# How to use font awesome with ABCpdf 11

Tags: abcpdf

webSupergood recently announced that with ABCpdf 11 they are now officially supporting Font-Awesome. Is there any example on how to use that?

As of today, the link at the [feature list page](https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm) only redirects to the Font Awesome page.

I would merely like to add a Font-Awesome icon to my document, no need to render any external page.

Answer (score 0):

[Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) is supported by the new ABCChrome HTML engine in ABCpdf 11 - and the default settings are the ABCChrome engine with JavaScript enabled. You can convert a URL (including a "file://" URI) using `Doc.AddImageUrl`, or an HTML string with `Doc.AddImageHtml`. And the [Paged HTML Example](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/13-pagedhtml.htm) applies for HTML that may take up more than one PDF page.

If there is any latency/delay in accessing web fonts, you can make ABCpdf wait e.g.

```
    doc.HtmlOptions.RepaintDelay = 2000;
    doc.HtmlOptions.RepaintTimeout = 5000; // default
    int htmlID = doc.AddImageUrl(theURL);
```